# Multiple values in name=cat doesn't work

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I am trying to initiaze to the 'cat' variable with multiple values (to make a php array). The problem is that I am getting every time the last one value.
Thus, I replaced in my html code  the  `name='cat'` to `name='cat[]'` but it doenst work.

Now I have the following clean code

Beginning code:
**PHP Code**

```
<?php
                    $args = array( 'taxonomy' => APP_TAX_CAT, 'selected' => $field['cat'], 'hierarchical' => 1, 'class' => 'text required', 'show_option_none' => __( '-- Select One --', APP_TD ), 'hide_empty' => 0, 'echo' => 0 );
                    $select = wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
                    $select = preg_replace('"-1"', "", $select); // remove the -1 for the "select one" option so jquery validation works
                    echo $select;
                ?>
```

and I change it to this:

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
                    $args = array( 'taxonomy' => APP_TAX_CAT, 'selected' => $field['cat'], 'hierarchical' => 1, 'class' => 'text required', 'show_option_none' => __( '-- Select One --', APP_TD ), 'hide_empty' => 0, 'echo' => 0 );
                    $select = wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
                    $select = str_replace('id=', 'multiple="multiple" id=', $select);
                    if (is_array($taxonomy_default)) {    
                        foreach ($taxonomy_default as $key => $post_term) {
                            $select = str_replace(' value="' . $post_term . '"', ' value="' . $post_term . '" selected="selected"', $select);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $select = str_replace(' value="' . $taxonomy_default . '"', ' value="' . $taxonomy_default . '" selected="selected"', $select);
                    }
                    $select = preg_replace('"-1"', "", $select); // remove the -1 for the "select one" option so jquery validation works
                    echo $select;
                ?>
```

**HTML Code**

```
    <select name='cat' multiple="multiple" id='cat' class='text required'>
<option value=''>&#8211; Select One &#8211;</option>
<option class="level-0" value="2">something1</option>
<option class="level-0" value="3">something2</option>
<option class="level-0" value="4">something3</option>
<option class="level-0" value="5">something4</option>
</select>
```

Also,  i can handle the 'cat' taxonomy from that code:

```
    $fields = array(
        'post_title',
        'cat',
        'tags_input'
    );

    // match the field names with the posted values
    // this process is to prevent unexpected field values from being passed in
    foreach( $fields as $field ) {
        $posted[ $field ] = isset( $_POST[ $field ] ) ? appthemes_clean( $_POST[ $field ] ) : '';
    }
if ( $posted['cat'] > 0 )
            $post_into_cats[] = get_term_by('id', $posted['cat'], APP_TAX_CAT)->slug;
```

I made some more replaces with the `str_replace` but it didnt work as well.

**HTML Code:**

```
<select name='cat[]' multiple="multiple" id='cat[]' class='text required'>
<option value=''>&#8211; Select One &#8211;</option>
<option class="level-0" value="2">something1</option>
<option class="level-0" value="3">something2</option>
<option class="level-0" value="4">something3</option>
<option class="level-0" value="5">something4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What part that doesn't work? this part works fine for me..

```
<?php
  print_r($_GET);
  if(isset($_GET['cat'])) {
    echo 'selected: ';
    foreach($_GET['cat'] as $v) echo $v . ' ';
  }
?>
<form action=''>
    <select name='cat[]' multiple="multiple" id='cat[]' class='text required'>
        <option value=''>&#8211; Select One &#8211;</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="2">something1</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="3">something2</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="4">something3</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="5">something4</option>
    </select>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: my action type was $_POST. pff, I thought that it was GET by accident, My !@!#4@!# mistake.